# K6: How to Count error Bad Handshake (Websocket)

Tags: javascript, k6

Currently i’m working on the loadtest for websocket, then I got so much errors like this

[image]

Then i would to count how many errors that occurs, and provide it on the report.
And I tried this method:

```
let errHandshake = new Counter("error_handshake");

if (res.status === 101) {
    errHandshake.add(0);
  } else {
    errHandshake.add(1);
  }
```

But it didnt work, the report just shown 0.
like this
[image]

Can anyone have an idea or something that might help?

Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried using try catch method and it works perfectly!!

```
try {
// your ws.connect
// check for example
} catch(e) {
// here you can count it  ...  by for example increasing a Counter
// https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-metrics/counter
}
// this code will get executed regardless if there was an exception 
// so you might want to do `throw e` in the catch if you don't want that
```

[image: Error bad handshake]

refference: https://community.k6.io/t/how-to-count-bad-handshake-websocket/1038